# angular 2: passing parameters from nodes

Tags: angular, parameters, nodes

I would like to pass a parameter from a node, instead of a property. For example:

```
<!-- I would like to use this: -->
<navbar-comp>
  <items>
    <item label="Page 1" path="/page1" />
    <item label="Page 2" path="/page2" />
    <item label="Section 3">
      <item label="Page 31" path="/section3/page1" />
      <item label="Page 31" path="/section3/page2" />
    </item>
    <item label="Page 4" path="/page4" />
  </items>
</navbar-comp>

<!-- instead of this: -->
<navbar-comp [items]="items"></navbar-comp>
```

How can I read the "items" contents from my component? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can access content of a component's node with ViewChild() or ContentChild() decorators. check out the docs